# Use foreach loop in javascript in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, for-loop, laravel-blade

I have data am looping from controller and i have a graph script and i want to loop that data in the script so that it can draw the graph based on that data

In controller i have

```
$records = Products::select('price')->get();
```

and in blade i have

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    theme: "light2",
    title:{
        text: "Simple Line Chart"
    },
    data: [{        
        type: "line",
        indexLabelFontSize: 16,
        dataPoints: [

            @foreach($records as $prc)
            { y: $prc->price},
            @endforeach


        ]
    }]
});
chart.render();

}
</script>
```

Original script

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    theme: "light2",
    title:{
        text: "Simple Line Chart"
    },
    data: [{        
        type: "line",
        indexLabelFontSize: 16,
        dataPoints: [
            { y: 500 },
            { y: 400 },
            { y: 250 },
            { y: 310 }
        ]
    }]
});
chart.render();

}
</script>
```

Its giving me a blank page, how can i go about doing it

Comment: Take a look at the laravel.log to get more details on a possible error

Comment: I am pretty sure it should be `{{$prc->price}}` to display the looped values. So all in all: `{ y: {{$prc->price}} },`

Comment: `@foreach($records as $prc)` starts a PHP block `<?php foreach($records as $prc) { ?>`, but you then tried to use `$prc` inside your JS code: `{ y: $prc->price }`; you need another PHP block, which is what `{{ ... }}` does: `{ y: <?php echo e($prc->price); ?> }`. This could all be avoided if you don't mix languages, i.e. convert `$records` to a JS variable, _then_ loop it, as opposed to looping your PHP variable in JS, like `let records = {{ JS::from($records) }};`, then `records.forEach(function(record) { return { y: record.price }; });`: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#rendering-json

Answer (score 2):

[Solution from @Aless55](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74976768/use-foreach-loop-in-javascript-in-laravel/74976885#comment132311703_74976768) works perfectly fine

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    theme: "light2",
    title:{
        text: "Simple Line Chart"
    },
    data: [{        
        type: "line",
        indexLabelFontSize: 16,
        dataPoints: [
            
            @foreach($records as $prc)
            { y: {{$prc->price}} },
            @endforeach
        ]
    }]
});
chart.render();

}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this piece :

```
<script>


window.onload = function () {
    var records = "<?php echo $records ?>"
    var data = records.map((function (record) {
      return {y: record.price}
    }))
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
      animationEnabled: true,
      theme: "light2",
      title:{
        text: "Simple Line Chart"
      },
      data: [{
        type: "line",
        indexLabelFontSize: 16,
        dataPoints: data
      }]
    });
    chart.render();
  }
</script>
```